# Why does linux/unix lacks in UI?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-distro

I have worked with many linux or unix os? Why is the user interface (UI) not so rich in its look compared to other windows or mac?

Comment: You can change or configure the graphical user interface (by switching to some other desktop environment or window manager). And it is a matter of opinion. For some people, free software is more important than look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we can back up and talk about the Linux and open source world for a minute, as opposed to the specific kernel and core operating system:

Open source communities organize and manage projects differently than for-profit companies. Different groups have different priorities and can produce really [cutting-edge 3d desktop effects](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4QokOwvPxrE) and incredibly [lean minimalist interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aBlackbox_on_Debian.png). The cool part is that the underlying operating system, core toolset and software management systems are largely the same either way.

Anyway this isn't really a programming question and is probably off-topic. I think you're going to strike a nerve, though, because it's *almost* like saying open-source OSs are inferior in some way to Windows/Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to just use Unix for Unix and Linux systems, as I'm not concerned about any of the hair-splitting distinctions between the two.

Unix has traditionally been a "programmer's" O/S.  It was meant to be powerful, flexible and simple.  This has often run contrary to the principles behind GUIs -- at least as many people see them.

While Unix has extended its reach and of course gotten GUIs long ago, it still has a reputation as a "programmer" system, and this shows.  Additionally, being able to swap out components (including the UI) is a pretty big deal in their culture, and this explains a lot of what you see.

So if something seems awkward or primitive, chances are that its main design criteria were flexibility and programmability, rather than ease of use (which may have been a criterion, but would have been trumped by the other two).